# Web-верстка: CSS -> media-запросы и iPad`s Safari

Tags: ipad, css3, android, выравнивание, css

Приветствую.
Прошу помочь разобраться с media-запросами. Проблемная страница тут: http://kenka.mastersoftonline.ru/1/full/?page=index

**Источник проблемы**

Есть общий контейнер содержимого страницы *div#page* (дефолтная ширина – как для блока), который содержит элементы *article* (margin: 0px auto). Такая вот разметка:

```
<div id="page">
    <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </article>
</div>
```

После этого идут медиа-запросы:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1124px) {
  #page > article,
  .main-width {
    width:800px !important;
    padding-left:0px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 924px) {
  #page > article,
  .main-width {
    width:600px !important;
    padding-left:0px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;
  }
}
```

**Суть проблемы**

При отображении на iPad-е (да и в webkit-браузерах Android-а) article располагается не по центру, а сбивается к левому борту (ведет себя, как будто "margin: 0px").

Да и [[[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)(max-width: 1124px) работает так, как будто ширина значительно меньше (пробовал на 3-м iPad-е, у которого ширина вьюпорта 2048px – в альбомной ориентации). Кроме того, заметил, что при повороте девайса в портретную ориентацию, [[[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)(max-width: 1124px) не реагирует, будто так и осталась такая же ширина. Видимо, надо еще опрашивать media-аргумент *orientation*. Хотя, на обычных машинах этот аргумент лишь отражает соотношение сторон, насколько мне известно.

Для понимания происходящего сделал [тестовую страницу](http://kenka.mastersoftonline.ru/1/screentest/index.php), но проверить не могу, так как остался без девайса. Есть ли у вас опыт или соображения на этот счет? Или если кто-то, у кого есть iPad, может хотя бы сказать, что же отображается на тестовой странице в обеих положениях девайса, буду признателен.

Comment: Загляните [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460871/incorrect-width-in-android-webkit-browser)

Comment: @Bars, есть расширение к ФФ ,который эмулирует IPhone 

http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: @Bars если ещё нужна помощь, то нужен сам код цельный и описание проблемы.

Comment: Да уж 7 лет прошло, столько воды утекло :) Да и описание проблемы, мне кажется, дано исчерпывающее, просто безнадежно устарело. Судя по оставленному мною же ответу, помощь не нужна более, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что дочерний элемент выходил за пределы родительского таким образом:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
    margin: 0px -50%;
}
```

И хотя установлен `overflow:hidden`, браузер считал своим долгом показать всю ширину дочернего элемента. Ни в одном из десктопных браузеров этого не наблюдалось.